# getting touch coordinates from panel with a background image in sencha touch

Tags: image, panel, extjs

I am working with a sencha panel in the below fashion.
Is there a way to attach a handler say like touch which can return the coordinates of the touch

```
var world_map = new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            style: 'background-color:black',
            autoScroll:true, 
            html:'<img id="w_map" src="./images/worldmap.png" width="90%" height="90%"></img>'

        });
```

The basic idea is to be able to detect the points where the user touches, is this possible using such a panel ?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible, and rather easy by using advanced listener options. The trick is to set the element property on the listener so that you are binding tap events to the DOM element over the component.

Here is a working example on Sencha Fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8ua

```
var world_map = new Ext.Panel({
    fullscreen: true,
    style: 'background-color:black',
    autoScroll: true,
    html: '<img id="w_map" src="./images/worldmap.png" width="90%" height="90%"></img>',
    listeners: [{
        event: 'tap',
        element: 'element',
        fn: function(event) {
            console.log(event);
            alert('Touch Position: ' + event.touch.pageX + ' ' + event.touch.pageY);
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: That's a blast from the past. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: We love answering old questions. I'm sure other people have had the same question over the last three years!